# React-Redux: Mutating the state to emulate action side-effects with redux-undo

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability, undo-redo

I have a few fields that, when updated, change the href of an image (which is really an endpoint of an external API that generates a PNG based on text input).

When that image loads, it triggers an action to update another component to match the image size (that it can only get after the image has finished loading). I set `redux-undo` to exclude that action from the history since it's not a user action.

**Here's my problem**: When I do an action that does NOT trigger a change, then undo that action, the state is wrong since the size has changed in between user actions.

An idea I had was to mutate the state (yeesh):

**In reducer**

```
case 'UPDATE_TARGET_SIZE':
    /**
    *  HERE BE DRAGONS
    *  I am also mutating the current state since this action needs to
    *  NOT count as an user action
    */
    state.targetWidth = action.targetWidth
    state.targetHeight = action.targetHeight

    return {
        ...state
    }
```

While it works with no apparent drawbacks... it feels like a dirty hack. Is there another way of doing so or is it safe as long as I know why I'm mutating the state?

Can a lib like `redux-saga` help me? I admit I have not read its documentation since I am not making "real" API calls and I don't want to have an overkill solution.

**Edit :**

Here's a better example:

I type in a text input, which causes the href to change. A new image is loaded, which triggers the action that is excluded from the history. At that point, the history does not have the modification of that last action.

If I do an action that copies that part of the sate (in the right reducer), the state is fine. If I do an action that touches only another reducer, it will still be wrong.

So when I press undo, I undo to the wrong state. But if I get that action to mutate the state, then it's always valid.

Comment: As I was reading this I was thinking, redux-sage might be a good solution for this and then I saw your question. Yes, I think redux saga would be very helpful for this. Give the docs a read through, I think you'll like what you find.

Comment: Thanks Dude (great Nick). I'll take a look when I get back on that horse and update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a lib like redux-saga help me? I admit I have not read its
>   documentation since I am not making "real" API calls and I don't want
>   to have an overkill solution.

`Redux-saga` allows to perform custom side effects and introduce process manager since it has own event loop. Applying to original task, `saga` can help with splitting action with request and response in time.

Typical use case is emitting action with postfix `_REQUEST`, like `LOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST`, which intercepts with saga manager and does not pass into reducers. Then after async operation is done, `saga` emits `_SUCCESS` or `_FAILURE`-like action, dependent on sucessfullity of operation. That actions passed into store and applied with reducers.

Also, there is ideology called `optimistic update`. In that case `_REQUEST` event passed into store, but if action is failed, saga sents compensating event, which rollback optimistic action

Comment: After using `redux-saga` for a while, I've managed to fix my problem by managing these actions in transactions. Thanks. :)